# Hive query to find percentage value

Tags: hive, subquery, hiveql, percentage, bigdata

The columns of the table I am working on is customer_id,operating_system,device_type,transaction_id,transaction_time.

I want to find out the % of the operating system used by the customer for the transactions done on mobile/tablet device in past 360 days.

Basic approach is : number of transactions where device type in(mobile/tablet) and timestamp is past 360 days group by customer _id,operating_system * 100 / total number of transactions done by particular customer for device type in (mobile/tablet) regardless of the operating system.

How can I write query to find the output as : customer_id,operating_system,% of operating system used

thank you in advance!

Comment: following is the query i have prepared.I am not sure weather it will work or not.                                                                                               Select t.customer_id,t.operating_system,100*( count(t.transaction_id)  / q1.total  )
From
table t,
(select count(transaction_id) as total from table where device_type in (mobile,tablet) and transaction_time 360
Group by  customer_id 
) q1
Where 
device_type in (mobile,tablet) and  transaction_time 360
Group by customer_id,operating_system

Answer (score 0):

In the subquery `s` below the total count for consumer and count for operating sytem are calculated. Since analytical functions are used, the number of rows remains the same as in source dataset. That is why you need to aggregate by consumer_id and operating_system. Use `max` or `min`:

```
    select --group by consumer_id and operating_system
           customer_id,
           operating_system,
           max(operating_system_cnt)                    operating_system_cnt,
           max(total_cnt)                               total_cnt,
           max(operating_system_cnt)*100/max(total_cnt) operating_system_percent
    from
    ( 
    select   --calculate total count and operating_system_count  
    customer_id, 
    operating_system,
    count(transaction_id) over(partition by customer_id, operating_system) operating_system_cnt,
    count(transaction_id) over(partition by customer_id) total_cnt
    from your_table
    where --your filter conditions here for mobile/tablet and last 360 days
    )s
group by
        customer_id, 
        operating_system
```

Comment: Thank you for the query.Just one question.We need to count the total number of transaction (transaction_id-unique for each transaction)so can we find out the count of all the transaction with out using transaction_id in a query ?

Comment: I do not completely understand your data. Is it possible duplicates for transaction_id for one customer and operating system? Please post the data example.

Comment: Fixed query. I didn't check it, cannot do it right now, maybe there are some other bugs.